# number of divs with the same name and same parent, return count individually

Tags: jquery

How to write a jquery code so as to find the individual count of the div with the class "aaa" in both the div with class "section-block" ?
I want the answer to be 4 and 3 respectively.
Please help

```
           <div class="section-block">
                            <div class="aaa"></div>
                            <div class="aaa"></div>
                            <div class="aaa"></div>
                            <div class="aaa"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="section-block">
                            <div class="aaa"></div>
                            <div class="aaa"></div>
                            <div class="aaa"></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: jQuery('.section-block').each(function() {
  var b = jQuery('aaa').length;
  console.log(b);
 });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.section-block').map(function(){
    $(this).find('.aaa').length;
})
```

This will work for any number of section blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".section-block").each(function() {
    var nbOfDivs = $(this).find(".aaa").length ;
    
    console.log(nbOfDivs) ;
  }) ;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-block">
                <div class="aaa"></div>
                <div class="aaa"></div>
                <div class="aaa"></div>
                <div class="aaa"></div>
</div>
<div class="section-block">
                <div class="aaa"></div>
                <div class="aaa"></div>
                <div class="aaa"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// this gives total overall, result = 7
console.log( 
  $('.section-block').children('.aaa').length 
);

// one by one result = 4 and 3
$('.section-block').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).children('.aaa').length );
});

// this is for accessing of your interest
// result = 4
console.log(
  $('.section-block:eq(0)').children('.aaa').length
);

// 2nd one
// result = 3
console.log(
  $('.section-block:eq(1)').children('.aaa').length
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-block">
  <div class="aaa"></div>
  <div class="aaa"></div>
  <div class="aaa"></div>
  <div class="aaa"></div>
</div>
<div class="section-block">
  <div class="aaa"></div>
  <div class="aaa"></div>
  <div class="aaa"></div>
</div>
```